# How to change color of FloatingActionButton dynamically?

Tags: flutter, dart

How to change color of FloatingActionButton dynamically? I want to do this like this. But it doesn't work. How to do it to work?

```
Color _background = Colors.white;
Color _foreground = Colors.green[900];
FloatingActionButton(
                    heroTag: null,
                    elevation: 10.0,
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        _background = _foreground;
                      });
                    },
                    child: Icon(Icons.directions_walk, color: _foreground),
                    backgroundColor: _background,
                  ),
```

Comment: Could you provide some more context? If these variable declarations are in your `build` method, this will not work at all since they will be reinitialized every time the widget's built. You need to have these as properties of a StatefulWidget's State class.

Comment: It works well. Please provide more code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code actually should be ok, I think the problem is that your variables

```
Color _background = Colors.white;
Color _foreground = Colors.green[900];
```

are inside your build function.

For example:

this won't work

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Color _background = Colors.white;
    Color _foreground = Colors.green[900];
    return Scaffold(
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          heroTag: null,
          elevation: 10.0,
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              _background = _foreground;
            });
          },
          child: Icon(Icons.directions_walk, color: _foreground),
          backgroundColor: _background,
        ),
        body: Text("Hello"));
  }
}
```

this will work

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  Color _background = Colors.white;
  Color _foreground = Colors.green[900];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          heroTag: null,
          elevation: 10.0,
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              _background = _foreground;
            });
          },
          child: Icon(Icons.directions_walk, color: _foreground),
          backgroundColor: _background,
        ),
        body: Text("Hello"));
  }
}
```

But it won't toggle your background color, this code can change the color only once.